# Sub Select with groupby in SQL Server does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my select

```
SELECT
    (FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'MM','PT-BR')) + '-' + (FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'yyyy','PT-BR')) AS 'year/mouth',
    ROUND(SUM(ITEM.VALORLIQUIDO),2) AS 'value'
FROM 
    FN_DOCUMENTOS DOC,
    CM_OPERACOESFATURAMENTO OFAT,
    CM_ITENS ITEM,
    PD_PRODUTOS PF
WHERE
    (OFAT.HANDLE = DOC.OPERACAOFATURAMENTO)
    AND (ITEM.DOCUMENTO = DOC.HANDLE)
    AND (PF.HANDLE = ITEM.PRODUTO)
    AND (OFAT.CODIGO IN (101,102,103,104,106,120,125,145,147,
     148,150,151,153,163,164,170,171,180,182,184,185,186,
     201,202,203,220,225,245,248,249,250,251,253,263,264,
     280,282,301,302,304,319,320,345,347,351,353,363,364,
     365,371,380,385)) 
    AND (DOC.FILIAL IN (1))
    AND (PF.MARCAPRODUTO IN (1,5))
    AND (DOC.DATAEMISSAO >= DATEADD(MONTH, -11, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'yyyy','PT-BR'),FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'MM','PT-BR')
ORDER BY  FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'yyyy','PT-BR'), FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'MM','PT-BR')
```

And this is my result from brand "1" and "5"

```
 month - year  |    value
    11-2017        7793.85
    12-2017        90862.51
    01-2018        681044.4
    02-2018        862552.22
    03-2018        963484.25
    04-2018        1127765.61
    05-2018        1485678.23
    06-2018        1249055.52
    07-2018        2098446.61
    08-2018        1765752.61
    09-2018        1139268.88
    10-2018        679253.04
```

What I need its one 3rd column with value from others brands, (2, 3, 4).

I can't create sub-select because I get an error from view to "group by".

Comment: Please use the `JOIN` clause for joins. This way the `WHERE` clause will be clean and free of relationships.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `3rd columm with value from others brands,` explain the logic and show us what the final result looks like

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

You could use all required data and split it into two columns using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'MM','PT-BR')) + '-' + (FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'yyyy','PT-BR') AS 'year/mouth',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN PF.MARCAPRODUTO IN (1,5) THEN ITEM.VALORLIQUIDO END),2) AS 'value',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN PF.MARCAPRODUTO IN (2,3,4) THEN ITEM.VALORLIQUIDO END),2) AS 'other value'
FROM FN_DOCUMENTOS DOC
  INNER JOIN CM_OPERACOESFATURAMENTO OFAT ON DOC.OPERACAOFATURAMENTO = OFAT.HANDLE,
  INNER JOIN CM_ITENS ITEM ON DOC.HANDLE = ITEM.DOCUMENTO,
    INNER JOIN PD_PRODUTOS PF ON ITEM.PRODUTO = PF.HANDLE
WHERE
    (OFAT.CODIGO IN (101,102,103,104,106,120,125,145,147,
     148,150,151,153,163,164,170,171,180,182,184,185,186,
     201,202,203,220,225,245,248,249,250,251,253,263,264,
     280,282,301,302,304,319,320,345,347,351,353,363,364,
     365,371,380,385)) 
    AND (DOC.FILIAL IN (1))
    AND (PF.MARCAPRODUTO IN (1,2,3,4,5))
    AND (DOC.DATAEMISSAO >= DATEADD(MONTH, -11, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'yyyy','PT-BR'), FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'MM','PT-BR')
ORDER BY FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'yyyy','PT-BR'), FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'MM','PT-BR')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SELECT - Change the Group by

**From :**

```
GROUP BY FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'yyyy','PT-BR'),FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'MM','PT-BR')
```

**To:**

```
GROUP BY  (FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'MM','PT-BR')) + '-' + (FORMAT(DOC.DATAEMISSAO, 'yyyy','PT-BR'))
```